# Typescript: Infer type in extends clause

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function like,

```
function create<TData extends { id: Id }, Id extends number | string>() {
  
}

// Usage
type User = { id: number, name: string }

create<User, number>()
```

When using this, I have to pass generic type for both `TData` and `Id`. Is there a way to pass only `TData` and infer the type of `Id`? Like,

```
function create<TData extends { id: ??? }>() {
 // Get type of id here
}

// Usage
create<User>()
```

Comment: You can use `{id: number | string}` and then inside the function use `TData["id"]` (that is, an indexed access type; no need to “infer”). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write a full answer or find a duplicate target; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes it does. I ended up creating a type like this, but it's probably overkill. `type IdType<T> = T extends { id: infer R } ? R : never`

Answer (score 0):

You can [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `TData` to `{id: number | string}` and then compute your `Id` type via the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `TData["id"]`:

```
function create<TData extends { id: number | string }>() {
  type Id = TData["id"];
  return null! as Id; // just to see the type computation
}
```

That gives the following behavior:

```
type User = { id: number, name: string }
const r = create<User>();
// const r: number

const s = create<{ a: number, id: string }>();
// const s: string
```

In the case of `User`, the `Id` type is computed to be `number`, while in the case of `{a: number, id: string}`, the `Id` type is computed to be `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQHgCoAiWGiaAHtmACYDOiA3ojFQFyJggC2ARmiogB9ENKChhgA5ogC+APgAUASgYAoRIigBPAA5pEASSqIAvIkLEA2gCJmVgLoBuNYnRQQKJBwA2XgISIMOkMHRAB6UMQAKxARDThhNDQVaRUVLV1EAFUaPhMGJlZ2Ll4UABp2DE40NhExSRkVCARY-lNUTGwcbL4FRSdw5GaoFzYOHj5UprBYujb0LFxGDFHivnLmGtFxKTklfoipmc26iVSgA)